# Trying to save xml class to file and my password encryption is not saving

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I have the following class that I am using to save my settings:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using SSSBackup.MiscClasses;

namespace SSSBackup
{
  public class MySettings
  {
    public string FileList { set; get; }
    public bool EmailForFailures { set; get; }
    public string EmailAddress { set; get; }
    public string OutputDirectory { set; get; }
    public string OutputFile { set; get; }
    public decimal NumberOfBackupsToKeep { set; get; }
    public bool RetainDirectoryStructure { set; get; }

    // ftp1 settings
    public bool Ftp1Enabled { set; get; }
    public string Ftp1Server { set; get; }
    public int Ftp1Port { set; get; }
    public string Ftp1Username { set; get; }
    public string Ftp1RemoteDirectory { set; get; }

    private string _ftp1Password;
    public string Ftp1Password
    {
      set
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
          _ftp1Password = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
          _ftp1Password = EncryptString.Encrypt(value, "29dk23lh2");
        }
      }
      get
      {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ftp1Password) ? string.Empty : EncryptString.Decrypt(_ftp1Password, "29dk23lh2");
      }
    }

    // ftp2 settings
    public bool Ftp2Enabled { set; get; }
    public string Ftp2Server { set; get; }
    public int Ftp2Port { set; get; }
    public string Ftp2Username { set; get; }
    public string Ftp2RemoteDirectory { set; get; }

    private string _ftp2Password;
    public string Ftp2Password
    {
      set
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
          _ftp2Password = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
          _ftp2Password = EncryptString.Encrypt(value, "29dk23lh2");
        }
      }
      get
      {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ftp2Password))
        {
          return string.Empty;
        }
        return EncryptString.Decrypt(_ftp2Password, "29dk23lh2");
      }
    }
    
    private static string _settingsFile;

    public static XmlSerializer xs;
    

    static MySettings()
    {
      _settingsFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "sssbackup.xml");
      xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
      using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_settingsFile))
      {
        xs.Serialize(sw, this);
      }
    }

    public MySettings ReadFromFile()
    {
      if (!File.Exists(_settingsFile))
      {
        FileList = string.Empty;
        EmailForFailures = true;
        EmailAddress = "replace@this.com";
        OutputFile = @"c:\path\to\your\zip";
        OutputFile = "ZipFile.zip";
        NumberOfBackupsToKeep = 14;
        RetainDirectoryStructure = true;
        SaveToFile();
      }

      using (var sr = new StreamReader(_settingsFile))
      {
        return xs.Deserialize(sr) as MySettings;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The save seems to be working well except when I call `SaveToFile()`, the password is not encrypted. I have put debug points on the property and the conversion is happening, but it is not making it to the file.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: @PrabathYapa I got most of this code from a youtube video on how to save your settings as xml. I got it from that.

Comment: @ErocM serializer calls getter of your property, so it gets decrypted value of the password

Comment: @har07 any ideas how I get around this? Should I encrypt it at the save maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializer calls getter of your property, so it gets decrypted value of the password (@har07)

Change:

```
  get
  {
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ftp1Password) ? string.Empty : EncryptString.Decrypt(_ftp1Password, "29dk23lh2");
  }
```

To:

```
  get
  {
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ftp1Password) ? string.Empty : _ftp1Password;
  }
```

and whenever you need this pass in program, call:

```
string pass = EncryptString.Decrypt(Ftp1Password, "29dk23lh2");
```

Do the same for `Ftp2Password`.

You should save the key for en/decrypt as a constant variable (or one other way) that you can refer to it in your en/decypt function, that way it is easier to maintain and avoid mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking outside the box. I was trying to keep it in the xml class. I'll go this way then. Thanks for the info.